# file.write only write the first string of Regex Results

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write all regex strings found into a text file. When I run the script, it only writes the first string to the text file. What am I missing? Thanks for the assistance.

```
import re
import csv
import PyPDF2

#Path to file
CROZER = (r"C:\Users\PC\Documents\Prospect Data\Crozer Invoices\rest of inovices\Crozer.pdf")

#Reading PDF
doc = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(CROZER)
pages = doc.getNumPages()

#Search Pattern
PO = re.compile(r'PO[:]\s\w{3}\d{0,}|Invoice\s#:\s\d{0,}')
list = []

for i in range(pages):
    current_page = doc.getPage(i)
    text = current_page.extractText()
        #print(text)
    if re.findall(PO, text):
     CINV = (re.findall(PO, text))
    print(CINV)

    with open('CI.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf8') as file:
        file.write(str(CINV))
```

I tried the file write but not results.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `a+` mode if you want to append contents to the end of file instead of overwriting it with `w+`.

```py
with open('CI.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf8') as file:
```

> 1.2 Definition of open modes r, r+, w, w, a, a+:
>
> The r throws an error if the file does not exist or opens an existing
> file without truncating it for reading; the file pointer position at
> the beginning of the file.
>
> The r+ throws an error if the file does not
> exist or opens an existing file without truncating it for reading and
> writing; the file pointer position at the beginning of the file.
>
> The w creates a new file or truncates an existing file, then opens it for
> writing; the file pointer position at the beginning of the file.
>
> The w+ creates a new file or truncates an existing file, then opens it for
> reading and writing; the file pointer position at the beginning of the
> file.
>
> The a creates a new file or opens an existing file for writing;
> the file pointer position at the end of the file.
>
> The a+ creates a new
> file or opens an existing file for reading and writing, and the file
> pointer position at the end of the file.

[Source](https://mkyong.com/python/python-difference-between-r-w-and-a-in-open/#difference-between-r-r-w-w-a-and-a)